# How to create customized web parts using sharepoint designer 2007?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I want to create a new customized web part through sharepoint designer not using the default one. Can anyone tell me is this possible to do it in sharepoint designer? or do I need any other software to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, SharePoint designer doesn't do custom web parts.  You can do some work with dataview web parts to retrieve data from external systems, but for the most part you need Visual Studio to create a custom web part.  [Here is a basic tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25019/Developing-SharePoint-WebParts).

Comment: Thanks Robert, it is quite helpful. I am on the right direction now.